# Turn off responsiveness - turn on zooming in browser

Tags: html, css

I want to force browser, to set virtual viewport to a fixed value.
Typically the meta viewport in responsive page looks like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

i found a solution to set width to fixed value:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200px">
```

But unfortunately it works well only in chrome. What i want to get is with width lower than 1200 i want to turn on the zooming functionality.

Does anybody knows any other trick to do it?

EDIT

Actually the problem is, that i managed almost all layouts with bootstrap to achieve responsiveness. But client decided, that he don't want this page to be responsive, but make the width fixed regardless of device width and toggle horizontal and vertical scrollbars if needed.

What i am looking for is a realy easy warkaround, to do this without hudge style modifications.

Comment: `warning! opinion ahead!` With a proper design, you should solve this with [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to display the pages specifically for screen sizes/types. Eg. by using larger fonts or by presenting a specifically designed view for that particular screen size/type. If your visitor is inclined to use the zoom function, the (ui-)design should be revised.

Comment: Normally i use @media and all this responsive stuff, but that is not, what i want to get.

Answer (score 0):

**Give this a try in jQuery:**

```
if(screen.width < 1200){
    $("meta[name=viewport]").attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes");
}
```

Comment: That's opposite, to what i want to obtain. Rather i want to turn responsiveness off, that enabling it when `screen.width < 1200`